# Visual basic designer view not show [Visual studio community 2022]

Tags: vb.net, vs-community-edition

I'm trying to create a project in visual basic using vs community, to be specific this is the project that I choose when creating one [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay2i9.png)

But, whenever I create a project there's no designer view so I cant design my form. [this is what it looks like after creating a project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndEs7.png)

I've tried shift + F7 didn't work, I also tried altering the tools > web form designer > general also didn't work, but when I try to open a project that was created in another device somehow the designer view is visible and I'm able to design and code. I've uninstall and reinstall vs community and it didn't work.

Comment: Temporarily disable any installed security software and try again.

Comment: It looks like you created a Windows Forms app, but you're referring to the `web form designer` settings. If you actually wanted to build a Desktop app, not a Web app, Make sure the WinForms designer is enabled; in `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Preview Features`, see that the `Use the preview Windows Forms out-of-process designer...` option is ticked

Comment: It also appears that the Solution has not been loaded correctly. You should not see the `.sln` file in there and the Form's code file is not linked to its Designer file. It looks like you have opened the content of a Folder rather than a Solution

Comment: @Jimi `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Preview Features, see that the Use the preview Windows Forms out-of-process designer...` I tried this one, but it didn't work as well, how can I link my form to my designer file? I haven't touch anything in that project yet, it just loaded like that.

Comment: You *tried it*? What does it mean? Was it enabled or not? If it was not enabled (it usually is, but better verify) and you activated it, you then need to restart VS. Anyway, from the screenshot, the Solution is not loaded correctly. Close VS, goto the path where the Solution's files are stored, double-click the `.sln` file to open it again. If you get the same result, the Solution is broken, better create a new one

Comment: @Jimi yes it is enabled, I also tried opening the file by clicking the `.sln` file, still nothing, I also deleted the file and started a new project and still nothing

Comment: If it makes any difference, when I create a project with windows form app(.NET Framework) the designer view is automatically displayed